# ExpressJS: Mounting / Unmouting dynamic routes

Tags: javascript, express, react-hooks, jsx

I know that this is not a regular use case in the express world as routes are usually setup once, but I am in need to replace an existing route with an updated handler dynamically.

Use case is a little [framework](https://state-less.cloud/lists?fs) I wrote that allows you to build serverside components using JSX/TSX alongside a reactive coding style known from the frontend library React. (components, hooks, effects etc.)

A component would look like this

```js
const TodoItem = ({id}) => {
    const [completed, setCompleted] = useState(false, {key: 'completed'});
    const toggle = () => {
        setCompleted(!completed);
    }
    return <ServerSideProps
        completed={completed}
        toggle={toggle}
    >
        <Route 
            path={`/todos/${id}/toggle`}
            get={toggle}
        />
    </ServerSideProps>
}
```

Serverside components can be consumed by a frontend client and all props rendered on the server are transported over GraphQL, providing a 1 to 1 mapping of props (including functions)

The frontend can then call the `toggle` function received from the GraphQL client which calls the Server Side `toggle` function within the rendered component.

Similar to React on the frontend, this causes a **rerender** of the server side component.

The `Route` component allows you to expose HTTP endpoints in case you need to interact with a component over http. (e.g. providing an endpoint / hook for serviceworkers to call).

The `Route` component is pretty simple

```js
import { useClientEffect } from '@state-less/react-server';
import express from 'express';

function deleteRoute(router, path) {
    const ind = router.stack?.findIndex((route) => {
        return route.path === path;
    });
    if (ind !== -1) {
        router.stack.splice(ind, 1);
    }
}
export const Route = (props, { key, context }) => {
    const { app, path, get } = props;

    useClientEffect(() => {
        if ('get' in props) {
            deleteRoute(app._router, path);
            app.get(path, get);
        }
    }, [app, get, path])
    
    return null
};
```

Now suppose I invoke the http endpoint */todos/some-id/toggle*. This would call the `toggle` function and cause a rerender of the serverside component. This also rerenders the `<Route />` component with an updated `get` method.

I need a way that the HTTP endpoint always calls the latest reference of the `get` function.

The first render and invocation of the endpoint works fine. The state get's updated the server rerenders and all connected clients receive the updated state.

However when I invoke the endpoint a second time `express` calls the previous reference of the passed function, **not** the updated one. It needs an additional invocation of the route until `express` calls the updated reference.

It seems like `app._router.stack` is not the only place where references to the handlers are being kept.

I'm looking for a way to flush any existing references of route handlers for a given path to be able to reassing a new handler to the route dynamically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you've bumped into an interesting quirk with Express.js. Sometimes, even after removing a handler from `router.stack`, Express might still remember the old handler due to the way JavaScript manages closures and references.

Lets try this first. Instead of directly replacing the handler, why not wrap it in a proxy function? This way, you can update the proxy's target whenever you need to.

Here's a quick breakdown:

- Create a store (like a Map) to keep the latest handler for each route.
- When adding a route, use a proxy function instead of the actual handler.
- To update the handler, simply update the store. The proxy will always fetch from this store, ensuring it uses the latest handler.

Let's dive into the code:

```
// Store for the most recent handlers
const latestHandlers = new Map();

// Our Express proxy function
function handlerProxy(req, res, next) {
    const currentPath = req.path;
    const handler = latestHandlers.get(currentPath);
    if (handler) {
        return handler(req, res, next);
    }
    next(); // Move on if no handler is found
}

export const Route = (props, { key, context }) => {
    const { app, path, get } = props;

    useClientEffect(() => {
        if ('get' in props) {
            // Make sure the proxy function is registered only once
            deleteRoute(app._router, path);
            app.get(path, handlerProxy);

            // Update the handler in our store
            latestHandlers.set(path, get);
        }
    }, [app, get, path]);

    return null;
};
```

So, with this setup, even if Express tries to be sneaky and remember old handlers, our proxy will always ensure it uses the latest one from our store. Hope this helps you out! Let me know if you run into any other roadblocks. Cheers!

Comment: Awesome! Thank you very much for the quick and copy-pastable  answer. This is a clean solution, much better than tempering with internals of an external library :)